# Why isn't the image being scaled proportionally to fit inside the image view in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I've seen many StackOverflow answers that have been upvoted a lot and/or are set as the best answers, and there's a consensus that the following code scales an image proportionally to fit inside an image view.

```
self.photoTakenImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
self.photoTakenImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self.photoTakenImageView setImage:self.photoTaken];
```

In addition, I have tried placing the call to set the image of the image view both

1. after setting the contentMode and clipToBounds, as above, and
2. before, as below, to no avail.

Alternative:

```
[self.photoTakenImageView setImage:self.photoTaken];
self.photoTakenImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
self.photoTakenImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

photoTaken and photoTakenImageView are properties of a class, as follows:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *photoTakenImageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *photoTaken;
```

I expect to see an image shrunk proportionally in the UIImageView, which is a 100x100 pixel square situated at the top-left corner of the window, but what I actually see is the image not being resized and spilling out of the UIImageView.

I'd really appreciate some help as to why these lines of code, which seem to have been accepted as best answers and upvoted in multiple questions, don't work for me.

Comment: You left out some important info. What do you actually see compared to what you expect?

Comment: Try setting the image view's frame after setting the image view's image.

Comment: Please set a background color on the imageView, so not set the image, see if the image view now appears the size that you think it is.